# White Screen of Death - Wp-Admin

Tags: php, wordpress

Since this morning I am getting the white screen of death when I try to access wp-admin (http://www.vilastennisacademy.com/wp-admin/).

I have read several threads about this error and tried to apply several possible solutions - unfortunately without success.

Solutions tried:

- Deactivating Plugins & Theme
- Searching several .php files (functions, wp-config, wp-settings,...) for empty lines of codes
- Also increased the memory to 64MB.

As already said, without success.

The last thing I did yesterday was adding a searchbar from the easyreservations plugin to a page - it worked perfectly fine yesterday until this morning. I didn't edit any .php file or similar.

This is btw the result of the debug:

> Notice: wp_register_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles
>   should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts,
>   admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see
>   Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added
>   in version 3.3.) in
>   /home/content/18/9366618/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3370
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /home/content/18/9366618/html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 898
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /home/content/18/9366618/html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 916
>
> Notice: add_custom_background is deprecated since version 3.4! Use
>   add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $args ) instead. in
>   /home/content/18/9366618/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3201
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant em_qtranslate - assumed
>   'em_qtranslate' in
>   /home/content/18/9366618/html/wp-content/themes/Vilas_2012/functions.php
>   on line 33
>
> Notice: get_theme_data is deprecated since version 3.4! Use
>   wp_get_theme() instead. in
>   /home/content/18/9366618/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3201

Not sure if any of these messages have something to do with the blank wp-admin page - i haven't changed anything in the code of any files since yesterday.

Any ideas what else I could try?

Thank you!

Comment: Try clearing your cookies & cache? Also might want to try searching [wp.se](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Rename the directory of the theme you are using, and Wordpress will revert to the default TwentyFourteen theme and you will be able to access wp-admin and investigate the issues with your broken theme.

Comment: turn on php errors..

Comment: Thanks for the comments!

cleared cookies & cache, renamed theme directory and turned on php errors (see above debug report) - unfortunately without success.

i can access wp-login.php, but after i log in i receive again the blank page. however, i seem to be logged in as i see the edit menu appearing when i am on the homepage...

Answer (score 0):

I did a backup and reinstalled the wp-core files from the latest wp build. It must have been a corrupt core file that caused the white screen of death.

Thanks a lot for your support!